# iOS WidgetKit: How to display the pictures in the album

Tags: ios, widget

I am developing Widgets for iOS and I really don't know how to display local images for the widgets.

```
func getUIImage(identifiers: [String]) -> UIImage? {
    if(identifiers.count <= 0){
        return UIImage()
    }
    let assets: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: identifiers, options: nil)
    if(assets.count <= 0){
        return UIImage()
    }
    let asset: PHAsset = assets[0]
    var img: UIImage?
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    options.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, _ in

        if let data = data {
            img = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    return img
}
```

But it doesn't work.